# consume a asp.net web service that returns json from an stand alone html page

Tags: asp.net, web-services, json

I've developed a web service in asp.net and am able to test it from an in-project aspx page and can readily display the information that was returned in JSON format.

I now need to consume the web service from a stand-alone html page.

Does someone have experience with this?  I'm puzzled by the part that would replace this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~\MyService.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

If this is not possible with straight html and javascript, can someone show me a stand-alone php page that would do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this link:

http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Use JQuery

www.jquery.org

Essentially, you make your Web Service script callable, just an attribute in your Web Service definition and you do:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "~/MyService.asmx/MyMethod",
    data: "{parameterName:'" aStringArgument + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
       var data = msg.d
       // Now var is an object with properties just like your object
    }
  });
```

Comment: Why do you have to use msg.d to get the result and not just msg?  I noticed that in the above link but I can't figure out why.

Comment: msg is the return object, and in his example the object has a property of "d".  You can define the web service return object any way you want.

Comment: The .d is due to how ASP.NET AJAX serializes objects returned from ASMX services and page methods in 3.5.  That's not something you can control unless you serialize the objects manually (not worth it).

Answer (score 1):

[Use JQUery.](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to access your webservice.

For example - if you have a json webservice defined like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public String Foo(String p1, String p2)
{    
    return "Hello World";
}
```

you could call it as follow:

```
var httpobj = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
//Gets the browser specific XmlHttpRequest Object
function getXmlHttpRequestObject() 
{    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
       return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} 

CallService()
{    
    //Set the JSON formatted input params    
    var param = "{'p1' : 'value1', 'p2' : 'value2'}";    
    //Send it to webservice    
    if(httpobj.readyState == 4 || httpobj.readyState == 0)
    {
        httpobj.open("POST", 'service.asmx/' + 'Foo', true);
       //Mark the request as JSON and UTF-8
       httpobj.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
       httpobj.onreadystatechange = OnSuccess;
       httpobj.send(param);
    }
}

//Called on successfull webservice calls
OnSuccess()
{
   if (httpobj.readyState == 4)
   {
       //Retrieve the JSON return param
       var response = eval("(" + httpobj.responseText + ")");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the ScriptManager (which adds over 100k of JS to your page), you can use [this method to use jQuery to connect to your web services](http://www.crossedconnections.org/w/index.php/2008/11/28/aspnet-web-services-from-javascript-with-jquery-without-the-scriptmanager/).